# How do I declare a working variable for minesweeper C++ program?

Tags: c++, minesweeper

I am currently working on solving a minesweeper C++ program, and I am unable to receive the correct output when the program finishes. I know it's a logic error, most likely from the "currentCell" variable, but I cannot figure out how to make it work. My output ends up like this: ____________________________________________________________________________________________________ ----

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// Global Constants
const int MAX_ROWS = 10;
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 10;
const int EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT = 0;
const char EMPTY_SQUARE_SYMBOL = '_'; 
const int BOMB_DIGIT = -1;
const char BOMB_SYMBOL = '#';
char currentCell = 0;

// Function Prototypes
void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void insertTheMineClues(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]);
void incrementTheNeighborSquares(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS], int row, int column);


// ############################################
int main(void)
{
   int gameBoard[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

   srand(time(NULL));
   fillTheGameBoard(gameBoard);
   insertTheMineClues(gameBoard);
   displayTheGameBoard(gameBoard);
   return 0;
} // End main


// ############################################
void fillTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
         for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
         {
            if (rand() % (MAX_ROWS - 3) == 0)
            {
               currentCell = BOMB_DIGIT;
            }
            else
            {
               currentCell = EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT;
            }
         }
      }
   }                    
} // End fillTheGameBoard


// ############################################
void displayTheGameBoard(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
         for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
         {
            if (currentCell == BOMB_DIGIT)
            {
               cout << BOMB_SYMBOL;
            }
            else if (currentCell == EMPTY_SQUARE_DIGIT)
            {
               cout << EMPTY_SQUARE_SYMBOL;
            }
            else
            {
               cout << currentCell;
            }
         }
      }
   }      
} // End displayTheGameBoard


// ############################################
void insertTheMineClues(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS])
{
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
         for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; column++)
         {
            if (currentCell == BOMB_DIGIT)
            {
               incrementTheNeighborSquares(board, row, column);
            }
         }
      }   
   }                  
} // End insertTheMineClues


// ############################################
// The function definition below is finished.  Make no changes to it.
void incrementTheNeighborSquares(int board[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS], int bombRow, int 
bombColumn)
{
   for (int row = bombRow - 1; row <= bombRow + 1; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )     
      {   
         for (int column = bombColumn - 1; column <= bombColumn + 1; column++)
         {
            if ( (column >= 0) && (column < MAX_COLUMNS) && (board[row][column] != BOMB_DIGIT) )      
               board[row][column]++;            
         } // End for column       
      } // End if   
   } // End for row
} // incrementTheNeighborSquares
```

Comment: So the way I read this question is. Output should look like this, then a big block of code, then what is the bug? You should work on making this into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Emphasis here is on the minimal part.

Comment: Check the compiler warnings. You might be told exactly what you're doing wrong. If not, turn up the compiler warning level. If it still won't tell you what's gone wrong, get a new compiler.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you? It's the best tool for figuring out logic errors, but it can't help if you don't use it.

Comment: It looks like `fillTheGameBoard` performs a lot of writes to `currentCell` and none whatsoever to `board`. I also don't understand the point of that `if((row >= 0 && row < MAX_ROWS))` line--that's guaranteed to be `true` by virtue of the fact that you're in the interior of the enclosing `for` loop at all, assuming you don't do horrible things to `row` during the body of the loop (which you don't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have at least two problems.

**The biggest one:**

You are setting the variable `currentCell`, but what you actually mean is to set **a cell in the board**!

Change all the assignments and references to this:

```
board[row][column]
```

**Second problem:**

The print function does not print the line feed. Just add `cout << endl;` to the end of the nested for loop to fix it.

**Third problem:**

This is not actually a problem but it makes my eyes hurt ;-)

You have:

```
   for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; row++)
   {
      if ( (row >= 0) && (row < MAX_ROWS) )
      {
```

That nested if makes no sense since it will **always** evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing gameboard to each of these functions, but the argument is never used